# network manager reinstall problem

Tags: networking, network-manager

I just reinstalled Network Manager, and it does not see any wifi networks around.

I did remove NM because I want fixed IPs both eth0 and wlan0 and I did like the "old" style, but now I am back - no WPA2 from command line ...

Install was fine with "sudo apt install network-manager" and a reboot

Now, if I go to "Settings" icon, then "Wifi" tab, there are no "visible networks"
And if I run "nmcli d wifi list", nothing but the header comes up (IN-USE, SSID, MODE...)

The networks are there, because another PC one meter from the previous "sees" all networks.

And if I start the command "sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grepp ESSID", all the networks come up.

Where is my configuration problem ?

pd.- network-manager service is running, but there are lots of warnings about /proc/4606/status (investigating)

Comment: Ubuntu is 18.04.4, hw Lenovo T60

Comment: Did you remember to remove all of your fixed-ip customizations? What do your /etc/netplan/* files say?

Comment: sorry, no /etc/netplan/ directory - is it positive ?

Comment: I am open to a "hard" reinstall, if you help me ...

Comment: Do you have the `netplan.io` package installed? Ubuntu 18.04 uses netplan instead of /etc/network/interfaces and other older tools.

Comment: how can I verify it ?

Comment: ok, i got it - https://netplan.io/faq - I go and see

Comment: *** sudo: netplan: command not found ***

Comment: well, I have netplan installed, but it did not detect my "old" configuration so config.yaml is empty - any way to fill it but manually ?

Comment: well, netplan installed, and configured by /etc/netplan/10_net.yaml, but still sees no wireless networks that are around - "sudo iw wlan0 scan" displays them